# How do I Apply a working Dropdown instead of a Text field in php

Tags: php, html

I am working on customizing a plugin, however my knowledge is currently lacking on the php side.

currently i have an Ad plugin in which you can sell ads per day, however my predicament is that i want to sell the ads only in packs of 30,60 & 90 days.

In this plugin upon typing a number of days this plugin calculates the amount and gives a result right under without anything pressed, so it is actively reading an input; however the only problem with this plugin is that it allows anyone to type a random number in there.

[image: front end view]

[image]

now the only real solution that i could think of was to make a drop-down with pre-existing values 30, 60, 90

My attempts thus far have been futile as i keep applying HTML `<Select>` (yes i had changed the wording from `<input` to `<select` and then added `<option value="value">value wording</option>`)techniques and it seems that anytime that i attempt to put a number for the value as one of the choices i get nothing but an empty drop-down, this then made sense to me since this is a PHP form and not an HTML form.

[image]

I was able to find where to code the changes, as i was able to find where the field is pulling from; here is the code:

(How should i proceed to make the changes that i want happen?)

```
<div class="control-group" id="total_days" style="<?php echo $date_dis;?>">

            <label class="ad-price-lable control-label"  width="40%"><div id="total_days_label"><?php JText::_("TOTAL_DAYS_FOR_RENEWAL");?>:</div> </label>
            <div class="controls">
                
                <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="totaldays" class="ad-pricing" id="totaldays" value="<?php echo $ad_totaldays ;?>" onchange="caltotal()" >
                

                
                <input type="hidden" name="ad_totaldays" id="ad_totaldays" value="<?php echo  $ad_totaldays;?>" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

now i am also assuming that out of this area, the main thing to be changed would be:

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="totaldays" class="ad-pricing" id="totaldays" value="<?php echo $ad_totaldays ;?>" onchange="caltotal()" >
```

of course, i could be wrong, but i really would appreciate help with this!

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've always done dropdowns

```html
<select form="examplef">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


<form id="examplef">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The php you're looking at is setting a value field for the inputs. This just means that something will be in the box already when you load the page.

Also keep in mind that just because you have predefined options doesn't mean you wont get unexpected input; Changing the options is as easy as right clicking

### PHP form vs HTML form

They are the same. The html `<form>` tag is a way to communicate with php. This tag will (most likely) have an attribute called "action" and "method". The action attribute specifies what to do with the collected information. You can think of it almost as an `<a href>` that includes data.

The method attribute is a little more complicated. It tells your browser how to send the data entered into the form. The two options are "GET" and "POST". the GET method is data put in the url. I'm sure you've seen youtube links with the `?id=`. This is just a GET variable included in the URL. The POST method is for secure data, or data that shouldnt be in the URL. If you would like to read more, W3Schools has a great document [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) or from Php [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Hi, this would be good, however it is still allowing the user to insert a value, where i am looking for just a dropdown in which they choose a value instead of typing one.

Comment: @JosephPortuondo not going to lie, copied the wrong code from my site lol sorry. It is fixed now

Comment: hey, I attempted the new code, however i ended up with a blank drop down. 

the code that i am editing:

                    '<input = "totaldays" type="text" maxlength="5" name="totaldays" class="ad-pricing" id="totaldays" value="<?php echo $ad_totaldays ;?>" onchange="caltotal()" >'

into this:

'<select form = "totaldays" type="text" maxlength="5" name="totaldays" class="ad-pricing" id="totaldays" value="<?php echo $ad_totaldays ;?>" onchange="caltotal()" ><option value="1">1</option></select>'

is something conflicting? if i put a word as value, then it shows,but not a number

Comment: @JosephPortuondo I set up a fiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sg8jm410/). The value field really doesn't matter in `<select>` tags. The first option will be default. Also as a quick side note: read the comments I left in the jsfidddle for more help with the id and such